# How to deselect the contents of a TextField in swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I have a simple desktop app where a TextField should be focused when the window loads. I have this working, but it's a little annoying that, having loaded the users content into the TextField, the entire contents of the field become selected automatically. The user may want to start editing the content, but they will rarely/never want to replace it all at once (imagine a text editor doing this, to see what I mean).

I see there is an Action for selectAll: but what I want is the opposite Action of selectNone:

I tried passing nil to the selectText method, but that doesn't work:

```
textField.selectText(nil)
```

I found a number of answers on StackOverflow that mention a selectedTextRange, but this appears to be outdated, because Xcode 6.3 doesn't recognize this as a valid property on TextField.

Can anyone explain how I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've dealt with NSTextFields to this level (I work mostly in iOS these days).

After doing a little digging I found this on the net:

```
NSText* textEditor = [window fieldEditor:YES forObject:textField];
NSRange range = {start, length};
[textEditor setSelectedRange:range];
```

window is the window containing your field, textField.

This requires the field editor to be managing your field, what can be done simply by previously selecting the whole text of the field using the selectText:sender method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final swift code that I got working based on what Duncan C posted:

```
if let window = NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow {
    let textEditor = window.fieldEditor(true, forObject: textField)!
    let range = NSRange(0..<0)
    textEditor.selectedRange = range
}
```